# import org.springframework cannot be resolved in

Tags: java, spring

Here is my pom.xml file.I am using eclipse .I am trying to make a helloworld spring application .T
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_hello_world_example.htm

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>spring-boot-gradle</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-gradle</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>13</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare dependencies to your maven project inside pom.xml. Once you update your maven project ( right click project and inside maven option update project). Those jars will be managed by your project and after that only you will be able to import spring specific classes. You can declare dependencies in pom.xml like below:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You can read more about maven dependencies in any beginner tutorial in  case you are not clear about maven basics.

Comment: thank you visal sharma.I am so much grateful to you

Comment: if the answer cleared your doubt could you accept the answer and upvote it.. Thanks :)